# Python chr() function returns wrong characters

Tags: python, file, char, int

I am trying to write a simple program:
In while loop, it accepts integer (guaranteed to be in range 0, 255), turns it into a corresponding character and writes this character in file until the input integer is -1.
I wrote it in C++ and it works well. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c;
    int p;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("a.txt");

    while(true){
        cin>>p;
        if(p == -1)
            break;
        c = p;

        myfile << c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to write the same program in python 3, the code is:

```
import sys

file = open("b.txt", "w")
while True:
    p = int(input())
    if p == -1:
        break
    c = chr(p)
    file.write(c)
```

The problem is, on some inputs, they give different outputs, for instance on input:

```
0
3
38
58
41
0
194
209
54
240
59
-1
```

C++ gives output:

```
0003 263a 2900 c2d1 36f0 3b
```

and python gives output:

```
0003 263a 2900 c382 c391 36c3 b03b
```

I have test cases so I know that the output of C++ is correct. 
What can be the problem?

Comment: How do you check the output?

Comment: Looks like you're writing UTF-8 sequences:  `bytes(chr(194), 'utf-8')
b'\xc3\x82'`.  Perhaps try forcing it to ISO-8859-1

Comment: @Zrax how exactly can I force it to?

Comment: By the way, in C++ it's implementation defined if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`. Assigning e.g. `240` to a `signed char` is not going to work very well and may not produce the results you expect.

Comment: I just don't get why I get -1 s. Then I will be banned for what? I formulated question pretty well and provided code and textual explanation.

Comment: @GeorgeTsertsvadze you can force an encoding type by putting `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-` at the top of your python script (without the <>)

Comment: @jhomr: No, that's the encoding Python will use to decode the source file itself, not the encoding the program will use for file I/O.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for clarification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept of "character" appears to be "byte". Python's is not; Python 3's concept of "character" is "Unicode code point", and how those are converted to bytes depends on the encoding.

If you want to write bytes, you should open your file in binary mode (in both C++ and Python), and you should change your Python code to pass `bytes` objects to `write`:

```
with open("b.txt", "wb") as file:
    while True:
        p = int(input())
        if p == -1:
            break
        # file.write(bytearray([p])) for Python 2 compatibility
        file.write(bytes([p]))
```